# bash egrep replace string with new line

Tags: bash, replace, grep, newline

I need replace all occurence of

```
<?php
<?php
```

to become just single

```
<?php
```

For now I have

```
egrep --include='*.php' -irl '<?php.*\n*.<?php' ./ | xargs sed -i -e "1s/.*//"
```

But that egrep replace FIRST line every time when find pattern in whole PHP file.

Comment: Look at the second answer of [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string) regarding matching multiline regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '!(/^<\?php/ && last ~ /^<\?php/);{last = $0}' input.php
```

If you want to run that on all files in the current folder use the help of `find`:

```
find -name '*.php' -exec bash -c '
    file=$1
    awk "!(/^<\?php/ && last ~ /^<\?php/);{last = \$0} " "$file" > "$file.tmp"
    mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
' - '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the command below (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string for explaination)

```
$ cat file1
<?php
<?php
totototo
tatata

$ cat file2
<?php
blabalbalbalabla

$ sed '/^<?php/{$!{ N;s/^<?php\n<?php/<?php/;ty;P;D;:y}}' file*
<?php
totototo
tatata

<?php
blabalbalbalabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase, this might do the job.

```
uniq input.php
```

This will suppress ALL duplicates lines. But it might suffice for your use case.

example :

```
> cat example.txt 
alice
alice
bob
alice
alice
bob
alice

> uniq example.txt
alice
bob
alice
bob
alice
```